# What does the [SIGINT] on my command line/terminal mean?

Tags: shell, terminal, fish

Sometimes while I am working on my terminal, `[SIGINT]` shows up before my caret.

1. What does this mean?
2. Why does typing `ls` remove that marker?

[image: Image containing [SIGINT]]

**Environment**

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, running `fish` as my shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was `bash`, I'd say someone had configured a `bash` function to run when generating your prompt. You can do all sorts of wonderful things with the `PS1` environment variable. However, as you state, you're using `fish` as your shell, so it's not the `PS1` environment variable.

This *appears* to be standard behaviour in `fish`, at least under unmodified `Ubuntu 20.04`, as evidenced by the following transcript, where I <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> the `sleep` command:

```
pax@paxbox ~> sleep 3600                # will ctrl-c this.
^C
pax@paxbox ~ [SIGINT]> true             # successful exit.
pax@paxbox ~> false                     # failed exit.
pax@paxbox ~ [1]>
pax@paxbox ~ [1]> fish -c 'exit 42'     # arbitrary exit value.
pax@paxbox ~ [42]>
```

And you can see *why* it does this by looking at the output of `functions fish_prompt`, as this is the function that gets called to generate prompts in that shell:

```
# Defined in /usr/share/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish @ line 4
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'
    set -l last_pipestatus $pipestatus
    set -l normal (set_color normal)

    # Color the prompt differently when we're root
    set -l color_cwd $fish_color_cwd
    set -l prefix
    set -l suffix '>'
    if contains -- $USER root toor
        if set -q fish_color_cwd_root
            set color_cwd $fish_color_cwd_root
        end
        set suffix '#'
    end

    # If we're running via SSH, change the host color.
    set -l color_host $fish_color_host
    if set -q SSH_TTY
        set color_host $fish_color_host_remote
    end

    # Write pipestatus
    set -l prompt_status (__fish_print_pipestatus " [" "]" "|" (set_color $fish_color_status) (set_color --bold $fish_color_status) $last_pipestatus)

    echo -n -s (set_color $fish_color_user) "$USER" $normal @ (set_color $color_host) (prompt_hostname) $normal ' ' (set_color $color_cwd) (prompt_pwd) $normal (fish_vcs_prompt) $normal $prompt_status $suffix " "
end
```

The line near the end, setting `prompt_status`, is adding `[SIGINT]` to the prompt being output, when the last command was interrupted (or adding any non-zero exit code for a normal completion).

If you want to *change* the behaviour of that function, you can make your own copy:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/functions
function fish_prompt >? ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
```

then make whatever changes you desire.

Comment: Solid explanation! Thanks for breaking down what the fish_prompt did, and referencing the actual source.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the last thing you started was killed by receiving the SIGINT signal, which is what typically happens when you press ctrl-c.

Running `ls` removes it because ls just runs to completion, so now the last thing wasn't killed by a signal.

Fish's default prompt shows this information because it's useful, e.g. if a program crashed it will show SIGABRT or similar.

To remove it you can pick a prompt that doesn't have it from the samples with `fish_config`, or make your own by modifying the `fish_prompt` function, e.g. via

```
funced fish_prompt
# try it out, once you are happy run
funcsave fish_prompt
```